# У меня не работает адаптив когда экран считаетсья десктоп, но когда ставлю тип экрана mobile всё работает(с помощю инструмента для верстки в гугле)

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, responsive

[image: вот сам макет, хочу что бы круги сзади мштабировались]

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.page-background {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #1F2326;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.page-background .circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.page-background .circle1 {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
  background: #FF4656;
  top: -75%;
  left: -25%;
}

.page-background .circle2 {
  max-width: 1500px;
  width: 1500px;
  max-height: 1500px;
  height: 1500px;
  background: #505155;
  top: 54%;
  left: 57%;
}

.page-background .circle3 {
  max-width: 260px;
  width: 260px;
  max-height: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  background: white;
  top: 8%;
  left: 86%;
}

.page-background .circle4 {
  max-width: 470px;
  width: 470px;
  max-height: 470px;
  height: 470px;
  background: white;
  top: 87%;
  left: 8%;
}

.page-background .circle5 {
  max-width: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #FF4656;
  top: 1%;
  left: 90%;
}

.page-background .circle6 {
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #505155;
  top: 24%;
  left: 95%;
}

.page-background .circle7 {
  max-width: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #505155;
  top: 86%;
  left: 6%;
}

@media (max-width: 1920px) {
  .circle1 {
    top: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/main.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="./pictures/general/logoVal.svg ">

  <title>Valorant</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page-background">
    <div class="circle circle1"></div>
    <div class="circle circle2"></div>
    <div class="circle circle3"></div>
    <div class="circle circle4"></div>
    <div class="circle circle5"></div>
    <div class="circle circle6"></div>
    <div class="circle circle7"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][введите сюда описание и[image: введите сюда описание изображения]зображения][2][на обеих изображениях одно и то же расширение но верстка выглядит по разномц](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMCiM.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы медиа запрос прописывали?! чтобы адаптивность работала

Comment: И было бы неплохо если бы вы код показали

Comment: DeniDove пробовал, не работают щас скрин скину

Comment: ничего не меняеться

Comment: circle1 это красный круг

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю то проблема у Вас заключается в томи что мета тег не совсем верный

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Попробуйте так поставить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да я специально этот метатег таким сдела,  у меня так на мобильном девайсе все отлично смотрится

Comment: ну я вернул обратно, но всё равно на мобильно девайсе верстка работает нормально,  на десктопе верстка ломаеться

Comment: Я правильно понимаю нужно разобраться с красным кругом?!

Comment: ага( больше всего он верстку ломает

Comment: у меня он даже почему то через медиазапрос не меняеться

Comment: код отправьте сюда, попробую у себя в редакторе протестить

Comment: ну вот  прекрипил я бы мог через медиа запросы всё поменять но они тоже почему то не работают(

Comment: слушай, у меня медиа запросы заработали, так что наверное можно считать вопрос решёным(вложеность помогла)

Comment: рад за Вас)))удачи)

Comment: спасибо збольшое за внимание)